# Is my static util method thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Util class with a utility methods as:

```
public static String formatAmount(String amount) throws Exception {
    return String.format("%,.2f", Double.valueOf(amount));
}
```

Is this method thread safe? I am not modifying amount any where else.

Secondly, I have another method as.

```
private boolean checkIfDateIsAHoliday(org.joda.time.LocalDate date) {
    boolean isHoliday = false;
    ....... 
    return isHoliday;
}
```

Is this method thread safe? I am not modifying date any where else.

Comment: First method is thread safe, second method...who knows? It's an instance method so it may modify object state or call another non thread-safe instance method (then it _may_ be not thread-safe). Without code there isn't answer.

Comment: are you modifying any instance level / class level fields in your second method?. If it is modifying only *method-local* variables, then it is thread safe.

Comment: Second method is only "thread safe" if the ....... is thread safe.  What did you leave out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread safety is all about accessing shared state. So if you want to know if a method is thread safe, you only have to check if it accesses state (=fields) that can also be accessed by other threads:

- If there is no such state, you're done - the method is thread safe.
- If there **is** such state, you have to check if it is accessed in a thread safe manner.

(See also http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-safety.html)

Your **first method** does not access any shared state (`String` is immutable, hence the parameter is thread-safe by itself). It calls two static methods (`String.format` and `Double.valueOf`) which might access shared state. Unfortunately, javadoc does not say anything concerning thread-safety of these two methods. Nevertheless we can assume that they are (otherwise almost all java applications were broken).

Your **second method** is thread safe concerning the code we can see (we can't argue about the code behind `.....`). Reason: You're just modifying local state (stack variable `isHoliday`). As local state cannot be accessed by other threads, this is thread-safe by definition.

Now just try to argue concerning the rest of your code (`.....`)!

Answer (score 5):

As always the hell is in the small details. Your first method is thread safe because it definitely does not change state of any class.

Your seconds method is available only partially. I do not know what is written in your code instead of `.......`. If you do not change state your any class there the method is thread-safe, otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 0):

For the First method it will be Thread safe But
It won't be Thread Safe for the method you have declared in the second

Comment: my Intention is the second method  may or may not be thread safe because we don't know the actual implementation

Comment: The First Method would not impact instance of the class So that is the reason why it is thread safe @TheLostMind

Answer (score 0):

The first one is thread-safe because you are only reading an immutable variable `String`.

Joda's `LocalDate` is also immutable. Therefore, assuming you are not reading or writing mutable class or instance fields, this method is also threadsafe.